# Does parser type conversion happen inside django tests?

Tags: python, django, argparse

I have defined a custom argument parser

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def custom_parser(value):
    # Do some actions with value
    return relativedelta(...)
```

I the use this in a management command as

```
parser.add_argument(
            "--tes",
            help=("blablaaa"),
            type=custom_parser,
            required=False,
            default='15s',
        )
```

Inside the `handler`, `tes` is correctly converted If I call the management command from the terminal directly.

```
def handle(self, *_args, **options):
    tes = options['tes']
```

This is correctly converted to `relativedelta` when I directly run the command. However, If I run this using `call_command('mycommand', tes='20s')` `options['tes']` is always a string.
Why is it not being converted? Can't seem to find something on the codebase that would explain it.

Comment: I know `argparse`, but only looked at `Django` years ago, so I have no idea what this `call_command` is doing, or how it is using the parser.

Comment: What is `call_command`? Is `options` supposed to be a namespace object?

Comment: Here is the `call_command` source code https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/management/__init__.py#L83
I resolved the issue by calling the `call_command` as follows
`call_command('mycommand', '--tes="20s"')`